# Please someone explain me this code in C language

Tags: c

this code is the solution to this problem https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/136/A in codeforces .... I understand the problem and I solved it but I don't understand this solution..
please someone explain to me this code

```
int n,a[101],i,j;

main()
{
    n||scanf("%d",&n);
    i-n&&(scanf("%d",a),a[*a]=++i,main(),printf("%d ",a[++j]));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to ask specific questions. What specific parts of this code do you not understand? What have you tried to understand so far?

Comment: Please see [“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/explain-x-to-me-questions-how-to-react) for why you need to narrow what you do not understand. I do not think the title you've chosen makes this Question easy to find from a search.

Comment: Don't bother with understanding this solution. It is obfuscation and horribly slow recursion on top of that. Looks like "code golf" and not a real program.

Comment: Also, `main()` instead of `int main()` with a function that lacks `return 0;` is invalid in any form of C. In C90, it would invoke undefined behavior if the caller (OS) used the result, in C99 and beyond it won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the operators `||` and `&&`, the code you posted is equivalent to the following:

```
int n,a[101],i,j;

main()
{
    if ( n == 0 )
    {
        scanf( "%d", &n );
    }

    if ( i - n != 0 )
    {
        scanf( "%d", a );

        i++;
        a[*a] = i;

        main(); //recursive function call

        j++;
        printf( "%d ", a[j] );
    }
}
```

In order to understand how this code works, all you have to do is run it line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471), while monitoring the values of all variables.